# How to migrate sonar embedded H2 database to oracle database

Tags: oracle, h2, sonarqube

I am trying to migrate sonar's H2(default database) to oracle database. For this I have edited sonar.properties file. I commented sonar URL and uncommented oracle URL(I made jdbc connection with oracle database and pasted that URL in sonar.properties). I have also changed sonar usename and password in sonar.properties. When I start sonar it gives me error and ask me to create tables in oracle database and even if I create tables in oracle it still ask me to create such more tables.

Do I need to make some more configuration/file changes? Am I missing something?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation which explains what to do to install a DB?... => http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/installing.html

Comment: Yes I have done all steps mentioned in the document..